# SQLAlchemy hash function

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a binary column that I want unique, but the database returns an error

> "ERROR: index row requires 28120 bytes, maximum size is 8191"

So I'd like to create the unique index on the hash, like in this solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859346/unique-constraint-on-bytea-data-type-on-postgresql) :

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_image_hash ON document (digest(blob, 'sha1'));
```

But I don't know how to do it with `SQLAlchemy`. This :

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Document(db.Model):
    blob = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    db.UniqueConstraint(db.digest(blob, 'sha1'), name='unicity_blob')
```

gives me the error

> "AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'digest'"

I'd like to have a function to replace this non-existing `db.digest`, but I can't find one. Is there one ? Or is there another way to do it ?

Comment: If you need an SQL function expression, use `func`, or in Flask-SQLA `db.func.digest(...)`.

Comment: Thanks ! With `db.func.digest` I have no error anymore, but unfortunately the constraint is not created, I don't know why.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975349/why-uniqueconstraint-doesnt-work-in-flask-sqlalchemy